# Как в списке словарей изменить ключи с помощью цикла?

Tags: python

К примеру, есть список словарей:

````
```
rule = [
 {"one": 5.0, "two": "ветер", "three": 300},
 {"one": 15.0, "two": "река", "three": 250},
 {"one": 20.0, "two": "лава", "three": 460},
]
```
````

Как с помощью цикла (или еще каким образом) соответствующие наименования ключей изменить на "один", "два", "три"? Есть конечно способ с rule.pop, но как его применить в списке словарей?

Comment: Можете показать свои попытки решения задачи?

Comment: Используйте списочное сокращение, а внутри него - словарное сокращение. И "на ходу" меняйте что вам нужно. Так проще всего будет.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что такового оформленного не имеется.

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1**

```
res = [{{'one': 'один', 'three': 'три'}.get(k, k):v for k, v in r.items()} for r in rule]
```

**вариант 2 (по сути тоже самое):**

```
res = [dict(zip([{'one': 'один', 'three': 'три'}.get(k, k) for k in r.keys()], r.values())) for r in rule]
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает идеально. Стрелочку вверх у вас я нажал, а форум что-то про публичное и не публичное написал, которое связано с тем, что я новичок )